# No puedo leer un archivo linea por linea

Tags: java

Estoy corriendo el siguiente código, pero únicamente me lee la primer linea del archivo TXT, estoy probando con pocas líneas por el momento (3 lineas), pero únicamente le agrega el ; a lo que esta separado por un espacio de la primer linea y despues se sale del ciclo While y me termina el programa

```
public class archivos {
    public String LeerTxt(String direccion){

        String texto = "";
    
            try{     
               BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(direccion)); 
               String bfRead;                                                                
            
               while((bfRead = bf.readLine()) != null){                         
                                                 
                 String array [] = bfRead.split(" ");
                   
                 for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i++) {
                       if(array[i].isEmpty()){
                                   
                        }else {
                           texto = texto+array[i].trim()+";";
                        }                 
                }                  
                             
               }     
  
           }catch(Exception e){System.err.println("No se encontro un archivo para convertir");}
    
           return texto;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int i = 0; i >= 0; i++`: ¿esta expresión está bien? Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Tienes varios detalles primero el como leer el archivo y también iterar sobre el array que debería ser: for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

Answer (score 1):

Para iterar sobre el array usa su longitud que obtienes mediante la propiedad `length`

```
 ...
 String array[] = bfRead.split(" "); 
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {                       
    ...
    ...
    ...
 }
```

Para leer las lineas usando `BufferedReader` se debe realizar de esta forma:

```
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Implementando lo anterior a tu método sería:

```
 public static String LeerTxt(String direccion){
    String texto = "";   
        try{     
           BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(direccion)); 
           
           String bfRead = bf.readLine();
            while(bfRead != null){      
              String array [] = bfRead.split(" ");                   
               for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {                       
                   if(array[i].isEmpty()){             
                       //No tiene elementos
                     }else {                          
                      texto += array[i].trim()+";";
                   }                
               }  
               bfRead = bf.readLine();
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {     
             System.err.println("IOException " + e.getMessage());
        }catch (Exception e) {
             System.err.println("Exception " + e.getMessage());
        }                
       return texto;    
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Es por la condición del bucle `for` , mira:

```
for (int i = 0; i >= 0; i++)
```

Al utilizar >= , el bucle cumplirá la primera iteración y nada más, pues en la siguiente sera mayor que cero. Si lo que quieres es iterar tres lineas, te recomiendo un cambio así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

De esta forma el bucle hará tres iteraciones.

Saludos !